# Custom Tag Description unable to display just below and outside of the Loop

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop, tags, description

Hello StackExchange Team! In my wordpress tags for custom post type, the code `<?php echo term_description();?> or`  outputs fine just outside and above the loop.

The problem I am having is that the same tag_description is blank when placed outside and below the loop below.

```
<?php
                            $countries_location = '';
                            $countries_location = apply_filters('zeetume_site_location_ads', $countries_location, 'search');
                            if (get_query_var('paged')) {
                                $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                            } else if (get_query_var('page')) {
                                // This will occur if on front page. 
                                $paged = get_query_var('page');
                            } else {
                                $paged = 1;
                            }
                            $category = array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'ad_tags',
                                    'field' => 'term_id',
                                    'terms' => get_queried_object_id(),
                                ),
                            );
                            
                            $ad_tags_args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'ad_post',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    $category,
                                    $countries_location,
                                ),
                                'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => '_zeetume_ad_status_',
                                        'value' => 'active',
                                        'compare' => '=',
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'orderby' => 'date',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'fields' => 'ids',
                                'paged' => $paged,
                            );
                            
                            $ad_tags_query = new WP_Query($ad_tags_args);
                            
                            if ($ad_tags_query->have_posts()) {
                            ?>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="posts-masonry">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                        <?php
                                while ($ad_tags_query->have_posts()) {
                                    $ad_tags_query->the_post();
                                    $pid = get_the_ID();
                                    $ad = new ads();
                                    echo zeetume_returnEcho($ad->zeetume_search_tag_list_layout($pid));
                                }
                                        ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                <?php zeetume_pagination($ad_tags_query);?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            } else {
                                get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');
                            }
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                            ?>
```

Please help me out, I am confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: var_dump your `term_description` variable and I suspect it'll end up empty.  What you're most likely looking at is that what generates the `term_description` variable you're echoing, is losing track of the term ID it's supposed to use to get the description outside of the loop.

Comment: There is no call to `term_description` in your code, can you update it to show where you're using it? `term_description` is meant to be used with the main query, but you've used a custom secondary query to display your posts instead, so it should never have worked at all regardless of where it was placed

Comment: @TomJNowell, I only echoed term_description or tag_description which is supposed to show custom post type description. I am sorry, I am still a beginner in wp coding.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Please how can I add term ID to get 'echo term_description' to work?